# How to make header top aligned exact on the page top?

Tags: geometry, height

My task is to render header (automatically) with the optional height.
So I can't understand the logic - how does header height works?

Me header contains `parbox` - the same `height` as i put in `headheight`
so when the height is 128 i've got this picture:

[image]

And when height is 32 I've got

[image]

So my question is: 
How to make header top aligned exact on the page top?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[left=72pt,right=72pt,
    headheight=124pt,
    voffset = 0pt,
    textheight =540pt
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{ \noindent\sbox{0}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\noindent\begin{tabular}{L{\textwidth}{p}}Non-disclosure agreement (NDA)\end{tabular}}}
\ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0<124pt
\dp0\dimexpr124pt-\ht0\fi
\makebox{\usebox{0}}\\}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    test
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `top` to the sum of your `headheight` and `\headsep`. Comment spurious spaces and remove the `\tabcolsep` in your table:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[left=72pt,right=72pt,
    headheight=124pt,
    top=\dimexpr124pt+\headsep\relax,% <- added
    textheight =540pt
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}


\newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \sbox{0}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{tabular}{@{}L{\textwidth}{p}@{}}Non-disclosure agreement (NDA)\end{tabular}}}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0<124pt \dp0\dimexpr124pt-\ht0\fi
  \makebox{\usebox{0}}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a magic!!